# how to return this variable from a button to be use for all the form

Tags: c#, excel, forms, variables, return

I'm trying to use a openfileDialog to insert a file from a button and then return the file name tu be use to read the file in another form

```
private void buttin1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OpenFileDialog File = new OpenFileDialog();
var FileName = File.FileName;
return FileName; 
}

private void buttin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataTable dtexcel = ReadExcel(FileName);
}
```

Comment: I presume you have done something like...
if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot `return` anything from your function `Button1_Click`, better set a variable that will be used by your MainWindow

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string yourFileName{get;set;}
    //...
    private void buttin1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog File = new OpenFileDialog();
        this.yourFileName = File.FileName;
    }
    
    private void buttin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(yourFileName!="" && File.Exists(yourFileName)
         {
             DataTable dtexcel = ReadExcel(yourFileName);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what if a i try to use the variable with another form?

Comment: then when you open the form, send the variable in it. I don't use WinForms, but ill be something like :

MyForm(int myInt)